# section_id: nil WHEN IT SHOULD BE section_id: 1

Tags: many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations

I'm following a LYNDA.COM tutorial with Kevin Skoglund. I was following along in the "Many-to-many" associations: Rich" video when I had a problem. The last line I ran (`section.section_edits`)
resulted in the following:

```
SectionEdit id: 6, admin_user_id: 1, section_id: nil,  ...
```

However Kevin's result on the tutorial was:

```
SectionEdit id: 1, admin_user_id: 1, section_id: 1,  ...
```

Obviously I have went back several times to try to find my error which is why my `SectionEdit id:` is different from his. BUT MY QUESTION IS: why is my `section_id: nil`

EDIT: 09/25/16

I entered `section.errors` in my command prompts but don't fully understand the console response. @AlterLagos

`irb(main):004:0> section = Section.create(:name => "Section One", :position => 1)
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Section id: nil, page_id: nil, name: "Section One", position: 1, visible: false, content_type: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):005:0> section.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x6340fe0 @base=#<Section id: nil, page_id: nil, name: "Section One", position: 1, visible: false, content_type: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:page=>["must exist"]}, @details={:page=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>`

Below is my consol and associated classes. THANKS!

**MY COMMAND PROMPT**

```
C:\Users\David\My Documents\sites\simple_cms>rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)

irb(main):001:0> me = AdminUser.find(1)
  AdminUser Load (4.0ms)  SELECT  `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users` WHERE`admin_users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
=> #<AdminUser id: 1, first_name: "David", last_name: "Boyette", email: "", hashed_password: nil, created_at: "2016-09-08 02:52:57", updated_at: "2016-09-08 02:52:57", username: "dboyette", salt: nil>

irb(main):002:0> me.section_edits
  SectionEdit Load (3.5ms)  SELECT `section_edits`.* FROM `section_edits` WHERE `section_edits`.`admin_user_id` = 1
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<SectionEdit id: 1, admin_user_id: 1, section_id: nil, summary: "Test edit", created_at: "2016-09-09 01:19:08", updated_at: "2016-09-09 01:19:08">, #<SectionEdit id: 2, admin_user_id: 1, section_id: nil, summary: "Test edit", created_at: "2016-09-10 00:05:56", updated_at: "2016-09-10 00:05:56">, #<SectionEdit id: 3, admin_user_id: 1, section_id: nil, summary: "Ch-ch-ch-changes", created_at: "2016-09-10 00:09:39", updated_at: "2016-09-10 00:09:39">, #<SectionEdit id: 4, admin_user_id: 1, section_id: nil, summary: "Test edit", created_at: "2016-09-17 03:32:13", updated_at: "2016-09-17 03:32:13">, #<SectionEdit id: 5, admin_user_id: 1, section_id: nil, summary: "Test edit", created_at: "2016-09-18 00:48:40", updated_at: "2016-09-18 00:48:40">]>

irb(main):003:0> section = Section.create(:name => "Section One", :position => 1)
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Section id: nil, page_id: nil, name: "Section One", position: 1, visible: false, content_type: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

irb(main):004:0> section.section_edits => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

irb(main):005:0> edit = SectionEdit.new
=> #<SectionEdit id: nil, admin_user_id: nil, section_id: nil, summary: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

irb(main):006:0> edit.summary = "Test edit"
=> "Test edit"

irb(main):007:0> section.section_edits << edit
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<SectionEdit id: nil, admin_user_id: nil, section_id: nil, summary: "Test edit", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>

irb(main):008:0> edit.editor = me
=> #<AdminUser id: 1, first_name: "David", last_name: "Boyette", email: "", hashed_password: nil, created_at: "2016-09-08 02:52:57", updated_at: "2016-09-08 02:52:57", username: "dboyette", salt: nil>

irb(main):009:0> edit.save
   (1.5ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.0ms)  INSERT INTO `section_edits` (`admin_user_id`, `summary`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 'Test edit', '2016-09-18 01:44:41', '2016-09-18 01:44:41')
   (69.3ms)  COMMIT
=> true

irb(main):010:0> section.section_edits
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<SectionEdit id: 6, admin_user_id: 1, section_id: nil, summary: "Test edit", created_at: "2016-09-18 01:44:41", updated_at: "2016-09-18 01:44:41">]>

irb(main):011:0>
```

**section.rb**

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :page
has_many :section_edits
has_many :editors, :through => :section_edits, :class_name => "AdminUser"
```

end

**Sections Migration**

```
class CreateSections < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
```

def change
    create_table :sections do |t|

```
  t.integer "page_id"
  # same as t.reference :page
  t.string "name"
  t.integer "position"
  t.boolean "visible", :default => false
  t.string "content_type"
  t.text "content"
  t.timestamps

end

add_index("sections", "page_id")
```

end
end

**section_edit.rb**

```
class SectionEdit < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :editor, :class_name => "AdminUser", :foreign_key => 'admin_user_id'
belongs_to :section
```

end

**section_edits migration**

```
class CreateSectionEdits < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
```

def change
    create_table :section_edits do |t|

```
t.references :admin_user
t.references :section
t.string "summary"
t.timestamps

end
add_index :section_edits, ['admin_user_id', 'section_id']
```

end
end

**Model: page.rb**

`class Page < ApplicationRecord

```
belongs_to :subject
has_many :sections
has_and_belongs_to_many :editors, :class_name => "AdminUser"
```

end
`

**Controller: Pages**

`class PagesController < ApplicationController
end`

**Migration: Page**

`class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|

```
  t.integer "subject_id"
  # same as t.references :subject
  t.string "name"
  t.string "permalink"
  t.integer "position"
  t.boolean "visible", :default => false
  t.timestamps

end
add_index("pages", "subject_id")
add_index("pages", "permalink")
```

end
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your console, clearly here is a problem:

```
irb(main):003:0> section = Section.create(:name => "Section One", :position => 1)
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Section id: nil, page_id: nil, name: "Section One", position: 1, visible: false, content_type: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

As you can see, is rolling back because of a validation error after to create the section, so the section object has an `id: nil`. I guess this is because a validation you didn't include in your question code, but after create the section, you could check easily the error in the console with `section.errors` and see what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add some information to this in case anyone else is having the same problem.

Alter Lagos is correct, there is a constraint on the Section that it must have a Page assigned. That is what is causing the call to fail.

To create the section object do the following: (It's not in the video).

```
page = Page.first
```

Then create the section and pass in the page.

```
section = Section.create(:name => "Section One", :position => 1, :page => page)
```

Answer (score 0):

In section.rb file -
make it
belongs_to :page, {:optional => true}

then in rails console run-
section = Section.create(:name => "Section One", :position => 1)

Cheers